# python regular expression on mactch switch outputs

Tags: python, regex

I had a string out from cisco switch command:

```
interface FastEthernet2/0/45
 switchport access vlan 703
 switchport mode access
interface FastEthernet2/0/46
 switchport access vlan 703
 switchport mode access
interface FastEthernet2/0/47
 switchport access vlan 703
 switchport mode access
interface FastEthernet2/0/48
 switchport access vlan 311
 switchport mode access
interface GigabitEthernet2/0/1
interface GigabitEthernet2/0/2
interface GigabitEthernet2/0/3
interface GigabitEthernet2/0/4
```

I'd like to use pyhon re to cut them by each interface, like:

```
['interface FastEthernet2/0/45 switchport access vlan 703 switchport mode access',
..ommited.., 'interface FastEthernet2/0/48 switchport access vlan 311 switchport mode access',
..omitted.., 'interface GigabitEthernet2/0/3', 'interface GigabitEthernet2/0/4']
```

I remembered that it can done by non-greedy to catch "interface" as a stop point for each patterns. Unfortunatly , this regex:"(interface.*?)" only get each "interface" but port number and detail. I can find a obvious end character to let re to get "interface" and following strings.

Maybe it's very easy, but I completely struck there...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python doesn't allow splitting by empty match, so you have to write a regex to match all the lines of each of the interfaces instead.

```
import re
re.findall(r'^interface.*(?:\n[\t ]+.*)*', input, re.M)
```

The regex starts matching from lines starting with `^interface.*`, then match new line character, and continue matching if there are one or more spaces `[\t ]+` at the beginning of the next line.

[**Demo on regex101**](https://regex101.com/r/wT1wK7/1)

Take note of how `\n` is included at the beginning of the repetition. This construction allows the regex to match the last record if the input doesn't end with new line.

Answer (score 0):

Just split according to the newline character which exists before `interface`

```
re.split(r'\s*\n\s*(?=interface\b)', s)
```

*Example:*

```
>>> import re
>>> s = '''interface FastEthernet2/0/45
 switchport access vlan 703
 switchport mode access
interface FastEthernet2/0/46
 switchport access vlan 703
 switchport mode access
interface FastEthernet2/0/47
 switchport access vlan 703
 switchport mode access
interface FastEthernet2/0/48
 switchport access vlan 311
 switchport mode access
interface GigabitEthernet2/0/1
interface GigabitEthernet2/0/2
interface GigabitEthernet2/0/3
interface GigabitEthernet2/0/4'''

>>> re.split(r'\s*\n\s*(?=interface\b)', s)
['interface FastEthernet2/0/45\n switchport access vlan 703\n switchport mode access', 'interface FastEthernet2/0/46\n switchport access vlan 703\n switchport mode access', 'interface FastEthernet2/0/47\n switchport access vlan 703\n switchport mode access', 'interface FastEthernet2/0/48\n switchport access vlan 311\n switchport mode access', 'interface GigabitEthernet2/0/1', 'interface GigabitEthernet2/0/2', 'interface GigabitEthernet2/0/3', 'interface GigabitEthernet2/0/4']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> re.findall(r"(interface\s*FastEthernet\d+\/\d+\/\d+[^\n]+\n[^\n]+\n[^\n]*)", YOUR_STRING, re.S|re.I)
['interface FastEthernet2/0/45\n switchport access vlan 703\n switchport mode access', 'interface FastEthernet2/0/46\n switchport access vlan 703\n switchport mode access', 'interface FastEthernet2/0/47\n switchport access vlan 703\n switchport mode access', 'interface FastEthernet2/0/48\n switchport access vlan 311\n switchport mode access']
```